# Different output when dividing same numbers by 2 but as int and float

Tags: c++, numbers, division

Why when i divide 1234567890 by 2 i get slightly different answer?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    float  m;
    int n;  
    cin>>n;
    n/=2;
    cout<<n<<endl;
    cin>>m;
    m/=2;
    cout<<m;
}
```

Comment: Please post the output also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to integer vs regular division. When dividing two integers the result is also an `int` this caused when you do `5/2` to return `2`. Floating point numbers and doubles do not have this problem. To bypass the int problem you can do `(double)five/two` using five and two as ints.

Comment: The issue you are talking about here is ints being truncated.  The OP is concerned about his floating result not accurately representing the real answer.  A `double` *would* solve his problem, though.  Because the number itself being equal, a double will have more precision.

Comment: Of course, the concrete value happens to be even, I.e., it doesn’t suffer from that particular issue.

Answer (score 4):

`float` uses 24 bits for the mantissa (sort of:IEEE use 23 plus one implicit bit) while `int` probably uses 31 (or 63; the other bit is effectively a sign bit). The value bits for an exact representation need 30 bits (I think) so the `float` value is rounded.